# Rubyinline returning wrong result for RARRAY_LEN

Tags: c, ruby

Why does this code return the wrong number of elements when I test it? It seems to be half of the correct value

I used RubyInline version 3.12.2. and Ruby 1.9.3

```
inline do|builder|
   builder.c <<-EOS
     VALUE arraylength( VALUE testarr){
       int arrlen = RARRAY_LEN(testarr);
       return arrlen;
     }
   EOS
end
```

This result is

```
arraylength([1,2,3,4,5])
#=>2
```

I expected

```
arraylength([1,2,3,4,5])
#=>5
```

Comment: Because it is inline C.

Comment: because called c from ruby.no good?

Comment: No problem. MadHatter's question does not make sense.

Comment: You may just need to convert the `int` to a `VALUE` e.g. `return INT2NUM( arrlen );` - I'm not sure, but that is what I would need to do if writing a more complete extension.

Comment: Wow!It's great!! Thanks NeilSlater.

Comment: Glad it worked! However, it may be more idiomatic to declare and return `int`, your problem was that you declared `VALUE` and returned an `int`, and it got coerced directly rather than properly converted.

Comment: I see.I study more...Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code is that you have declared the C function returns a `VALUE` (a long pointer type used to identify a Ruby object) but then return an `int`. The compiler can force a coercion here, and RubyInline may be suppressing a warning you get when this is compiled.

The end result is the method returns the Ruby `Object` with an `object_id` equal to the length of the array you passed in. For most small values of `int`, this is just a map to a `Fixnum` (i.e. what looks like the "wrong integer").

As it happens, `2.object_id == 5` which is why you get 2 when you expect 5.

The fix is to ensure you return the correct type. You could either return a `VALUE` like this:

```
inline do |builder|
   builder.c <<-EOS
     VALUE arraylength( VALUE testarr ){
       int arrlen = RARRAY_LEN(testarr);
       return INT2NUM( arrlen );
     }
   EOS
end
```

Or you could work directly in `int` and let RubyInline convert for you:

```
inline do |builder|
   builder.c <<-EOS
     int arraylength( VALUE testarr ){
       int arrlen = RARRAY_LEN(testarr);
       return arrlen;
     }
   EOS
end
```

I don't use RubyInline, but suspect this second version would be preferred when RubyInline can do the conversion for you. But under the hood it is probably altering the code to look like the first version anyway.